# Using fit_transform() and transform()

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

What I know is `fit()` method calculates mean and standard deviation of the feature and then `transform()` method uses them to transform the feature into a new scaled feature. `fit_transform()` is nothing but calling `fit()` & `transform()` method in a single line.

But here why are we only calling `fit()` for training data and not for testing data??

Does that means we are using mean & standard deviation of training data to transform our testing data ??

Comment: This is because you want to avoid [data leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-without-data-leakage/).

Comment: @petezurich In a what way?

Comment: @SamWong Have you looked into the linked article? That is a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fit` computes the mean and stdev to be used for later scaling, note it's just a computation with no scaling done.

`transform` uses the previously computed mean and stdev to scale the data (subtract mean from all values and then divide it by stdev).

`fit_transform` does both at the same time. So you can do it with just 1 line of code.

For `X_train` dataset, we do `fit_transform` because we need to compute mean and stdev, and then use it to scale the `X_train` dataset. For `X_test` dataset, since we already have the mean and stdev, we only do the transformation part.

**Edit**: `X_test` data should be totally *unseen* and *unknown* (ie, no info is extracted from them), so we can only derive info from `X_train`. The reason why we apply the derived mean and stdev (from `X_train`) to transform `X_test` as well, is to have the same "apple-to-apple" comparison for `y_test` and `y_pred`.

By the way, if the train/test data is split properly without bias, and that the data is sufficiently large, both datasets would have the same approximation to the population mean and stdev.

Comment: But the mean and stdev will be for values in X_train and not X_test, shouldn't mean and stdev for both the sets be different

Comment: X_test data should be unseen and unknown, so we can only derive info from X_train. For the purpose of apple-to-apple comparison, we apply the same mean and stdev to transform X_test. If the train/test data is split properly without bias, they should have the same approximation to the population mean and stdev